# function is giving back no response and no error

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I'm working with this code to modify the position of object according to the position of the mouse.

```
    function layerCss(parallax, px, offset, size, position, pointer) {
    var pos = [],
        cssPosition,
        cssMargin,
        x = 2,
        css = {};

    while (x--) {
        if (parallax[x]) {
            pos[x] = parallax[x] * pointer[x] + offset[x];

            // We're working in pixels
            if (px[x]) {
                cssPosition = position[x];
                cssMargin = pos[x] * -1;
            }
            // We're working by ratio
            else {
                cssPosition = pos[x] * 100 + '%';
                cssMargin = pos[x] * size[x] * -1;
            }

            // Fill in css object
            if (x === 0) {
                css.left = cssPosition;
                css.marginLeft = cssMargin;
            }
            else {
                css.top = cssPosition;
                css.marginTop = cssMargin;
            }
        }
    }

    return css;
}
```

Now I would like to try to modify the position of the objects with transform: translate(x,y) instead of left, top,

css. Position is giving me back 2 Values but the function don't work anymore

```
    function layerCss(parallax, px, offset, size, position, pointer) {
    var pos = [],
        cssPosition,
        cssMargin,
        x = 2,
        css = {};

    while (x--) {
        if (parallax[x]) {
            pos[x] = parallax[x] * pointer[x] + offset[x];

            // We're working in pixels
            if (px[x]) {
                cssPosition = position[x];
                cssMargin = pos[x] * -1;
            }
            // We're working by ratio
            else {
                cssPosition = pos[x] * 100;
                cssMargin = pos[x] * size[x] * -1;
            }

            // Fill in css object
            css.transform = 'translate(' + cssPosition[0] + 'px,' + cssPosition[1] + 'px)';


        }
    }

    return css;
}
```

I' trying to figure it out since 2 hours but nothing seems to work.
Hope you can help me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`cssPosition = pos[x] * 100;` would never return an array, yet you're accessing the first two indexes when building the translate rule.

```
'translate(' + cssPosition[0] + 'px,' + cssPosition[1] + 'px)'
```

It seems the same for `cssPosition = position[x];`, but this one could actually work, depending on what you pass into the function.

Make the new `cssPosition` an array with both dimensions, and your code will work.

Comment: i deletet the pixels and ratio part und added cssPosition = pos[x]; and alert(cssPosition); 

now i get unlimited alerts with 2 different numbers as long as i don't move the mouse but the transform still isn't working

Comment: And is `pos[x]` an array?

Comment: when i try alert pos[x] i also get unlimited alerts with 2 different numbers as long as i don't move the mouse

Comment: That's what I'm telling you the whole time. Read my answer, you need to make it an array.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Javascript. How can i turn it into an array and will it then still update as i move the mouse?

Comment: It should work normally then, yes. I need to see how you're calling the function, where are your coordinates stored?